# What's wrong in this query Mysql.?

Tags: php, mysql, insert

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'where id='29'' at line 4

```
insert into supplier_details 
set supplier_tempid='scacsscacsa', name='naman gupta  gupta', type='dvsvds',sex='male', 
pno='scaasc', postno='12345', mobile='sacevw', email='ewvdv', language='ewvdvwe', service='fwvdv', 
country='sdvdvsvds', registered='Yes', address1='2979 sec-32 A chandigarh road', region='ewv qecsdv', 
community='cdsdcdsv', about='hello', comment='vdsdsvewv' where id='29'
```

Comment: insert with where...no it should be update..

Comment: yea sorry guys it was update.. didn't notice my bad. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`INSERT` query not work with where condition. you should use `UPDATE` query.

```
update supplier_details set supplier_tempid='scacsscacsa', name='naman gupta  gupta', type='dvsvds',sex='male', pno='scaasc', postno='12345', mobile='sacevw', email='ewvdv', language='ewvdvwe', service='fwvdv', country='sdvdvsvds', registered='Yes', address1='2979 sec-32 A chandigarh road', region='ewv qecsdv', community='cdsdcdsv', about='hello', comment='vdsdsvewv' where id='29'
```

Comment: damn  my bad  actually i was updating but mistakenly write insert thanks. )

Comment: glad to know. you can accept the answer in that case.

Comment: yea i will definitely but have to wait for 8 more minutes.

Answer (score 0):

That is not how you `INSERT`. it is rather an `UPDATE` query.

> Notice: you have some errors in the query like
>   `language='ewvdvwe,`   `address1='2979` `sec-32 A chandigarh road',` and
>   where `id='29.` All of them missing `'` and one of them `sec-32 A chandigarh road',` with invalid `-`

The fix:

```
UPDATE  supplier_details 
        SET supplier_tempid='scacsscacsa', 
        name='naman gupta  gupta', 
        type='dvsvds',sex='male', 
        pno='scaasc', 
        postno='12345', 
        mobile='sacevw', 
        email='ewvdv', 
        language='ewvdvwe', 
        service='fwvdv', 
        country='sdvdvsvds', 
        registered='Yes', 
        address1='2979', 
        sec = '32 A chandigarh road', 
        region='ewv qecsdv', 
        community='cdsdcdsv', 
        about='hello', 
        comment='vdsdsvewv' 
        WHERE id='29';
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing insert and update syntaxes. It should be either

```
insert into supplier_details values('scacsscacsa', 'naman gupta  gupta', 'dvsvds','male', 'scaasc', '12345', 'sacevw', 'ewvdv', 'ewvdvwe', 'fwvdv', 'sdvdvsvds', 'Yes', '2979 sec-32 A chandigarh road', 'ewv qecsdv', 'cdsdcdsv', 'hello', 'vdsdsvewv')
```

or

```
update supplier_details set supplier_tempid='scacsscacsa', name='naman gupta  gupta', type='dvsvds',sex='male', pno='scaasc', postno='12345', mobile='sacevw', email='ewvdv', language='ewvdvwe', service='fwvdv', country='sdvdvsvds', registered='Yes', address1='2979 sec-32 A chandigarh road', region='ewv qecsdv', community='cdsdcdsv', about='hello', comment='vdsdsvewv' where id='29'
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to insert then the rite format is.

```
<?php

$dbc = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","database name");

$string = "INSERT INTO table_name(id, firstname, lastname) VALUES($_POST[id],$_POST[firstname],$_POST[lastname])";

$query = mysqli_query($dbc, $string);

?>
```

$_POST['something'] should be equal to name='something' inside the form field

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're trying to do:

```
UPDATE supplier_details SET supplier_tempid='scacsscacsa', name='naman gupta  gupta', type='dvsvds',sex='male', pno='scaasc', postno='12345', mobile='sacevw', email='ewvdv', language='ewvdvwe', service='fwvdv', country='sdvdvsvds', registered='Yes', address1='2979 sec-32 A chandigarh road', region='ewv qecsdv', community='cdsdcdsv', about='hello', comment='vdsdsvewv' WHERE id='29';
```

To change an already existed ROW, you need to use the UPDATE statement.